# Pandas: get second character of the string, from every row

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe, character

I've a array of data in Pandas and I'm trying to print second character of every string in col1. I can't figure out how to do it. I can easily print the second character of the each string individually, for example:

```
array.col1[0][1]
```

However I'd like to print the second character from every row, so there would be a "list" of second characters.

I've tried

```
array.col1[0:][1]
```

but that just returns the second line as a whole of col1.

Any advice?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use [`str`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html#text-string-methods) to access the string methods for the column/Series and then slice the strings as normal:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(['foo', 'bar', 'baz'], columns=['col1'])
>>> df
  col1
0  foo
1  bar
2  baz

>>> df.col1.str[1]
0    o
1    a
2    a
```

This `str` attribute also gives you access variety of very useful vectorised string methods, many of which are instantly recognisable from Python's own assortment of built-in string methods (`split`, `replace`, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

As of Pandas 0.23.0, if your data is clean, you will find Pandas "vectorised" string methods via `pd.Series.str` will generally *underperform* simple iteration via a list comprehension or use of `map`.

For example:

```
from operator import itemgetter

df = pd.DataFrame(['foo', 'bar', 'baz'], columns=['col1'])

df = pd.concat([df]*100000, ignore_index=True)

%timeit pd.Series([i[1] for i in df['col1']])            # 33.7 ms
%timeit pd.Series(list(map(itemgetter(1), df['col1'])))  # 42.2 ms
%timeit df['col1'].str[1]                                # 214 ms
```

A special case is when you have a large number of repeated strings, in which case you can benefit from converting your series to a [categorical](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html):

```
df['col1'] = df['col1'].astype('category')

%timeit df['col1'].str[1]  # 4.9 ms
```